# cgvg escape quotes

Tags: grep

Does anyone know a way with cgvg to escape quotes?  Normally I just use the opposite quote type (single vs double) when I need a quote in the string.  But sometimes I need both.  Like this:

```
cg '["'].*something.*["']'
```

Escaping the enclosed single quote doesn't help:

```
cg '["\'].*something.*["\']'
```

nor does a second or third layer of escaping:

```
cg '["\\'].*something.*["\\']'
cg '["\\\'].*something.*["\\\']'
```

Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you insert the quotes as escaped hex (ASCII)?

Comment: Nope.  It's treating that as literal text